# Landing Page Works - Linked Pages Don't - HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml

Tags: java, jstl, tomcat7

Landing Page Works - Linked Pages Don't - HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

I'm relatively new to java/tomcat so please be gentle.

I am moving Java web applications from Tomcat 5.5 to Tomcat 7.0.30.  There are 26  containers defined.  They work on the Tomcat 5.5 installation.  I have spent hours if not days reading and trying various things.  I have read the [jstl wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), interesting reading but to no avail.

The problem is that when you land on the host URL, the landing page comes up ok.  The landing page uses jstl to resolve images.  When the script attempts to 'window.location=""' I get the http status of 500.

The Tomcat 7 bin library does not have any of the JSTL libraries.  I'm relying on the lib directory under the WEB-INF file to contain the jstl library files.  From my perspective, I should be able to copy the files that are on the Tomcat 5.5 to the Tomcat 7.0 and it should run, assuming the server.xml is set up properly.

There appears to be no errors in the catalina.out file when it starts (other than when I touch one of the linked pages).

We do have a secure host that is defined with port 443.  I was able to copy the app to a directory under that directory and was able to get to it.  The links from that site worked!

While I'm at it.  If there's a context container defined in the 'META-INF' and a context container defined in the server.xml, which takes precident?  Enquiring minds want to know.

Thanks

An update:
It seems that if I deploy via placing a war file in the webapps directory; letting it create the directory and deploy the application the silly thing works!

Unfortunately, I need to deploy the application to a place outside the structure of the webapps directory.  (/web/httpd/abc.com)  In the server.xml file I defined the host as

```
<Host name="abc.com" appBase="/c:/web/httpd/abc.com">
```

What's more, my 'bug' is present in both my tomcat test bed which is on a Linux machine and my Windows PC.

Comment: Here's something to chew on.  It appears that if the jsp file is at the root level, there is no problem with the JSTL libraries.  The only time I get the '500' screen of purgatory is when the jsp is NOT at the root level.  Does this help anyone with where I should be looking at?